# Android project does not compile

Tags: android

When I try to compile my project, I get an error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/google/android/gms/internal/zzrn$1.class

---

I guess that problem concerns my dependencies. Here is a snippet of code:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'

compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

---

I was investigating, and try with the cmd and gradlew clean, but the problem still happen.

Anyone had the same problem and can tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

i found the problem, remove `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'` and change the version 9.6.1 a 8.3.0 of `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'`